# Custom environment move to end of chapter

Tags: sectioning, positioning, environments, chapters

I have written a custom `example` environment for formatting mathematical worked examples.  These are currently included in the sections they are related to, however are sometimes looking a bit cluttered.

I am considering grouping all the examples at the end of each chapter.  Can you think of a simple way I can rewrite my custom environment so that it moves all of the text to the end of each chapter, displaying them in the order they were written in? (Kind of like some of the endnotes packages I suppose!)

Thanks!

**EDIT** - adding MWE requested in comments...

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}


%%%%% SET UP THE ENVIRONMENT HERE %%%%%
\newcounter{examplecounter}
\setcounter{examplecounter}{0}
    \newenvironment{example}[1]{
        \refstepcounter{examplecounter}%
        \vspace{3mm}\hspace{3mm}\\%
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.07cm}\\%
        \textbf{Worked Example \arabic{examplecounter}: #1}\\
    }{
        \hfill\\%
        \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.07cm}
    }


\begin{document}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
        \blindtext

        \begin{example}{Some are several pages}
           \blindtext[10]
        \end{example}

        \section{First Section}
            \blindtext
            \begin{example}{Others are shorter}
                Second Example
            \end{example}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe the `endfloat` package in conjuction with the `newfloat` package can help?

Comment: Perhaps you can have write the contents to a file (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115379/write-and-read-from-a-latex-temporary-file) and `\include`, then reopen the file at the end of each chapter.

Comment: Please add to your question a minimal, yet complete document showing the current definition of your `example` environment. I ask you, because having this definition, we can be sure that possible solutions will effectively work for your definition.

Comment: Thanks Gonzola, I originally didn't have a MWE because it was a general query, but I'll add one

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following **Alan Munn**'s comment, here's one possible option using the [`newfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newfloat), [`endfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) and [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) packages: first, we declare a new floating environment `example`, and then we declare this environment as a delay-aware one.

The heading for each `example` can be obtained using a customized version of `\caption` with empty argument.

Some options were added to allow more than one object appearing in the same page and to prevent automatic generation of a list of examples at the beginning of each group of delayed examples; only one list is produced at the beginning of the document, using `\listofexamples`.

Using `\processdelayedfloats`, the examples can be processed at the end of every chapter and, thanks to a redefinition of `\chapter` provided by **Werner**, this is done automatically.

The code:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage[nomarkers]{endfloat}

% the delayed floats will be automatically processed at the end of each chapter
\let\oldchapter\chapter
\renewcommand\chapter{%
  \processdelayedfloats%
  \oldchapter}
\AtEndDocument{\processdelayedfloats}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment{example}
\DeclareDelayedFloat{example}{Examples}

 % we allow several floats per page
\renewcommand\efloatseparator{\mbox{}}
% no automatic list of examples; it will be manually generated with \listofexamples
\SetupDelayedFloat{example}{nolist}

% captions flushed to the left margin and boldfaced
\captionsetup[example]{singlelinecheck=off,labelfont=bf,skip=.4\baselineskip}

\begin{document}
\listofexamples

\chapter{Test Chapter One}
\begin{example}
\caption{}
Test example one.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
\caption{}
Test example two.
\end{example}

\chapter{Test Chapter Two}
\begin{example}
\caption{}
Test example three.
\end{example}

\begin{example}
\caption{}
Test example four.
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

And the document obtained:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Noe that additional information has been added to the original question, it is clear that my previous suggestion won't be useful, since some examples might contain page breaks and floating objects don't admit them.

A possible solution now is to use the `collect` environment from the [`collect`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/collect) package; below is an example of its usage.

We declare the `exa` collection and define a new environment `example` which uses the `collect` environment; the two mandatory arguments of `collect` are used for the formatting (see remark below). The `etoolbox` package was used to patch `\includecollection`, so that this command will produce a heading in the form of an unnumbered chapter.

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}% openany just for the example
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{collect}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\definecollection{exa}
\newcounter{examplecounter}[chapter]

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{example}[1]
  {\@nameuse{collect}{exa}{%
    \refstepcounter{examplecounter}
    \vspace{3mm}%
    \noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.07cm}\par\nobreak\noindent
    \textbf{Worked Example \arabic{examplecounter}: #1}\par
    }{%
    \par\nobreak\vskip.1\baselineskip\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{0.07cm}%
    }
  }%
  {\@nameuse{endcollect}}
\makeatother

\pretocmd{\includecollection}{\chapter*{Examples for Chapter~\thechapter}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{example}{Some are several pages}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{example}

\section{First Section of Chapter One}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{example}{Others are shorter}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\includecollection{exa}

\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{example}{Another short example}
\lipsum[2]
\end{example}

\section{First Section of Chapter Two}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{example}{Another long example}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{example}

\includecollection{exa}

\end{document}
```

Images of the output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I left the horizontal rules of the original definition, but if the examples will be collected at the end of every chapter in a section of their own, the rules are superfluous and can be removed.

Comment: Hey Gonzalo, thanks for your detailed answer! I'll give this a go and see how it looks - although I'm not sure how this will handle multiple page examples?

Comment: @mecharius You're welcome! My code won't allow page breaks inside the `example` environment, since the environment is treated as a floating object and floats don't admit page breaks. Now that you've provided some more information, a convenient solution can be designed.

Comment: @mecharius I've updated my answer with a solution allowing page breaks; I am working on some improvements, so I will be updating the answer in the next hours.

Comment: Great, thanks - didn't really require the MWE, but should have mentioned originally that the examples "could extend over multiple pages"... In any event, its good to have solutions for both cases! Thanks again.

Comment: @mecharius right; all that was needed was the info about multiple pages ;-). I am glad I could help.